# Проблема с открытием нужного модального окна в php

Tags: javascript, php

столкнулся с данной проблемой, есть конкретный массив с именами. Нужно сделать модальное окно с выводом выбранного имени. Но вместо того, дабы открывать модальное окно с выбранным именем - открывает только с последним, то есть последним элементом массива. В панели разработчика видно, что содержание модального окна генерируется правильно. Для лучшего понимания - код и фото прилагаю.

```
<?php
                    for ($i =0; $i<sizeof($arrayOfNicknamesCC); $i++){

                        echo '<li><a class="js-click-modal">'.$arrayOfNicknamesCC[$i];

                        echo '</a></li>';
                        echo '<div class="container_modal">
                            <div class="modal">
                                <div class="header">'.$arrayOfNicknamesCC[$i].'
                                </div>
                                <div class="body"><p>'.$arrayOfNicknamesCC[$i].'</p>
                                  <a class="btn js-close-modal">Close</a>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>';
                    }
                ?>
```

Код JS

```
<script>
    $('.js-click-modal').click(function(){
        $('.container_modal').addClass('modal-open');
    });

    $('.js-close-modal').click(function(){
        $('.container_modal').removeClass('modal-open');
    });
</script>
```

И фото того, что получается. Я полагаю, что нужен каждому отдельное модальное окно генерировать, но может будут какие-то другие идеи реализации?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.js-click-modal').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("li").next('.container_modal').addClass('modal-open');
});

$('.js-close-modal').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.container_modal').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

Comment: Прекрасно, огромное вам спасибо)))

Comment: @Glechik Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Простите, что обращаюсь в комментах. Но повторно встрял на похожей задачке. А как подстроить код, если ссылка на модальное окно находится в ячейке таблицы? к Примеру: 
`<table>
<td><a class="js-click-modal">Ssilka</a></td>
<div class="container_modal">
         <div class="modal1">
                 <div class="header"><p>Name</p></div>
                 <div class="body">
                         <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a>
                  </div>
          </div>
</div>
</table>`

Comment: @Glechik а `tr` где?

Comment: Простите, опечатался 
`
<table> <tr><td><a class="js-click-modal">Ssilka</a></td></tr> <div class="container_modal"> <div class="modal1"> <div class="header"><p>Name</p></div> <div class="body"> <a class="btn1 js-close-modal">Close</a> </div> </div> </div> </table>
`

Comment: @Glechik Поместите модальное окно внутрь того же `tr`, что и ссылку.

Comment: Сделал, но, к сожалению не помогло [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/georgin/eabcp5qv/1/), если будет желание, посмотрите пожалуйста, а то пока не сильно получается(

Comment: @Glechik https://jsfiddle.net/d9bfsur1/